# Android billing - error you own this item

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have a ndroid application with in-app billing. I want a have a subscription. i see a google sample. i introduced billing in my application. i purchase one item. but i have problem. i click a button 'purchase' start intent ... .after closing this intent(text: you own this item, i click ok) if i want click this button again app is crushed.

logs

i own this item.

```
05-31 19:02:10.416: D/Finsky(3313): [1]CarrierParamsAction.createCarrierBillingParameters: Carrier billing config is null. Device is not targeted for DCB 2.
05-31 19:02:10.436: I/SurfaceFlinger(1705): id=170(12) createSurface 0x3d364 (1x1),1 flag=0
05-31 19:02:10.441: E/Finsky(3313): [237] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramspt_jJJW_8KK4rjjCyMt7_w' failed!
05-31 19:02:10.456: D/dalvikvm(3313): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1269K, 11% free 15726K/17607K, paused 13ms+7ms
05-31 19:02:10.471: I/ClipboardServiceEx(1865): mCBPickerDialog enter case. MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG
05-31 19:02:10.471: D/CLIPBOARD(14751): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
05-31 19:02:10.476: I/ClipboardServiceEx(1865): mCBPickerDialog enter case. MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG
05-31 19:02:10.491: I/ActivityManager(1865): Displayed shortComponentName: +165ms
05-31 19:02:10.726: I/power(1865): *** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1 
05-31 19:02:10.726: D/PowerManagerService(1865): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
05-31 19:02:10.726: W/ActivityManager(1865): mDVFSLock.release()
```

in a second click i have

```
05-31 19:08:43.331: W/System.err(15461): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress.
05-31 19:08:43.331: W/System.err(15461):    at com.market.IabHelper.flagStartAsync(IabHelper.java:725)
05-31 19:08:43.331: W/System.err(15461):    at com.market.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:289)
05-31 19:08:43.331: W/System.err(15461):    at com.crystalreality.crystaltv.BillingActivity.performPurchaseSubscription(BillingActivity.java:65)
05-31 19:08:43.331: W/System.err(15461):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

i have a activityResult, but its code not execute

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
        if(requestCode == 0) {
            finish();
        }

        // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
            // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
            // billing...
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        }
    }
```

purchaseFlow is code from sample.
how i may fix it?

Answer (score 6):

That's a bug in the in-app billing IabHelper class (that is, it's my fault :-)). Please download the updated sample (with bug fixes) from:

http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/

The version in the SDK manager is a little bit out of date at the moment and doesn't contain the latest bugfixes.

Comment: i download sample. it works. Bruno , if i have 2 activity(native(c++) and usual(java with iabhelper)) , how i may call purhaseflow from native activity. in c++  i call method of usual activity(using jni) , this method call purchaseflow ..   in my app error is persist

Comment: I would kiss you if I could, @Bruno!! Been scratching my head for the past two days trying to figure out why my purchased subscriptions weren't being listed; updated to the new code you linked to, and it works great now. Thank you so much!