# Purchased subscription not returned in inventory

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've adapted the `play_billing` sample in the Google extras of the Android SDK to use my own app package name and public key. I was able to purchase a managed item as well as a subscription thru the app.

However, when I call methods such as `Inventory.getAllPurchases()` the subscription is not returned in the user's inventory, even after restarting and reinstalling the app.

```
@Override
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
{
    if(result.isFailure())
    {
        log.error("In-app billing inventory query failed: " + result);
        return;
    }

    for(Purchase purchase : inventory.getAllPurchases())
    {
        log.info("Purchase: " + purchase.getSku());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Purchase: premium
```

The regular, single-time purchase (`premium`) is output as you can see, but the subscription purchase (`paid_app`) is not. When I try to buy the subscription again it says I've already bought it:

[image: Error when trying to purchase the subscription]

I've tried everything I know, but I can't figure this out. Since the regular item is working as intended, I don't see why the subscription isn't being returned unless I'm totally off base on how that is supposed to work.

I have the APK uploaded as a draft. I have my email address on the phone in the testers list; the email is NOT my developer email. My subscription item is Active. The phone I'm testing on has the latest version of Google Play.

Edit: Still no luck. However, here's another update in case it's relevant. When I go into Google Wallet none of the transactions show up (ostensibly because they are test transactions). And for my test user account when I go into Google Play under subscriptions, it is not listed. Yet it won't let me purchase again. So not only do the purchased subscriptions not show up when I query for them, but they also are nowhere I can cancel to test again.

Any ideas here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by chance when I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861060/848393) and decided to try the updated code linked there.

Apparently the *`play_billing` sample listed in the SDK manager is **outdated***, and all the classes in the `util` package need to be replaced by the `util` packages from [this up-to-date project](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/).

After I replaced the old `util` package with the new one, my subscription gets listed along with the regular `premium` item!!!

```
Purchase: paid_app
Purchase: premium
```