# Android billing- error you already own item: Carrier billing config is null. Device is not targeted for DCB 2

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm trying to test a trial subscription using Android billing v3. The app already have products on production but I'm trying to also add a subscription. Everything works fine when I buy the trial subs for the first time. Then I cancelled it (wait hours and days) and then when I try to buy it again there's an Android Dialog with the message: You already own this item. Both Google Play app and my server side app confirm that the subscription is cancelled.

The logcat window shows this output:

```
03-24 15:41:53.722: D/IabHelper(21333): Constructing buy intent for com.MYAPP.freetrial, item type: subs
03-24 15:41:53.732: D/Finsky(20292): [1056] InAppBillingUtils.pickAccount: com.MYAPP:      Account determined from installer data - [UAHnZq8S3yArGc_6ew11RBHr0DE]
03-24 15:41:53.742: D/IabHelper(21333): Launching buy intent for com.MYAPP.freetrial. Request code: 10001
03-24 15:41:53.742: D/audio_hw_primary(181): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
03-24 15:41:53.742: D/ACDB-LOADER(181): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
03-24 15:41:53.742: I/ActivityManager(580): START u0 {cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.IabV3Activity (has extras)} from pid -1
03-24 15:41:53.812: D/Finsky(20292): [1] CarrierParamsAction.createCarrierBillingParameters: Carrier billing config is null. Device is not targeted for DCB 2.
03-24 15:41:53.812: E/Finsky(20292): [1054] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'params5wrD2REIodMwVQIkVi-biw' failed!
03-24 15:41:53.872: W/GLSUser(17314): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
03-24 15:41:53.882: I/ActivityManager(580): Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.IabV3Activity: +99ms
```

I had to add to onQueryInventoryFinished BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED checked because the subs was recreated on the server side everytime I query the inventory:

```
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
    mHelper.flagEndAsync();
    if (result.isFailure()) {
        // complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
        return;
    }

    // Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
    if (result.getResponse() == IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
        return;
    }
    consumePuchasedItems(inventory);

    // Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");

}
```

My app is signed with release certificate, the build code+version numbers are exactly the same than in Developer Console.

I'm using the latest code from http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/ (14/12/2013)

I have already checked [Android billing - error you own this item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860586/android-billing-error-you-own-this-item) and other similar posts, but it is not working.

I would appreciate any suggestion.Any idea? I'm working on this for several days and still no solution. The subscription process seems to work well for the first time, I tried with different account. The problem arises when I cancel it and try to re-buy it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you cancel a subscription you still have access to that subscription until the end of the subscription period.  This is Google's implementation. And that is why there are no refunds for cancelled subscriptions because Google still allows access to the subscription for the entire subscription period even when cancelled.

What cancelling a subscription does is to stop subscription renewal.

This is why even though you cancelled your subscription that you cannot immediately purchase it again.  You should be able to re-purchase once the current subscription period ends.